# Grails - Changes domain object in beforeValidate() not persisted

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain object that I am changing a property value on inside of the beforeValidate() event.  If this property is the only one changed on the object, nothing seems to get persisted to the database.  I've looked in the debugger, and see the object has changed.  But when I call save(flush: true), the new value is not persisted.

What could I be doing wrong?

It does work if another property was changed outside of the beforeValidate() event though.

Environment: Grails 2.0.1, failOnError is turned on globally

## Edit

I am calling `validate()` on my object manually and I see the `beforeValidate()` getting called.  Before I call `save(flush: true)` I logged the following:

```
log.debug("isDirty() = ${myObj.isDirty()}")
log.debug("changedVal = ${myObj.val}")
log.debug("dirtyPropertyNames = ${myObj.dirtyPropertyNames}")
```

which printed out

```
isDirty() = false
changedVal = my new value
dirtyPropertyNames = []
```

So it seems that hibernate is not recognizing that the object is dirty.  How can I make it see the object as dirty?

Comment: If the hibernate session has not been flushed, then the change won't have been persisted.  Try calling save(flush: true) to force a flush (and write to the DB).

Comment: I am calling save(flush: true). Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Ok, what about adding also `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`, i.e. maybe it's currently failing silently for some reason?

Comment: I've got `grails.gorm.failOnError = true` in the Config.groovy

Comment: Ok, just thought I'd ask the obvious questions.  Can't help you sorry.

Comment: Hey, just having a look at this link: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/09/16/gorm-dirty-checking-of-instance-and-properties/    I wonder if the object is not being marked as "dirty", and therefore not written, since your change is happening within the context of a hibernate event?

Comment: It does seem that my object is not marked as dirty.

Comment: Where are you calling `validate()` from? Is the object definitely attached to a hibernate session at that point?

Comment: Could you post some code? Like your beforeValidate() method and the piece where you save the object? Also, how many times does beforeValidate() gets called? Put a println inside it.

Comment: Thanks JonoB, I think I'm pointed in the right direction now.  It looks like my issue is coming from what I am doing in between `validate()` and `save()`. I need to detach from the session and then reattach after deleting an object due to our complex domain model. Right after the `validate()` my object is dirty, but after `discard()` and `attach()` it no longer is dirty, thus not saving.